# Signed java applet no longer works in any browser if I set the clock ahead on my computer

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate

I have a Java Applet (for a browser) signed and timestamped with a valid Code Signing Certificate from GoDaddy.  The code signing certificate itself expires in a few weeks.  Everything I've read says that the applet will still be valid after the Code Signing Certificate expires:

From [here](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/java-7-update-51-code-signatures-required.htm):

> If a timestamp is discovered, then the code signature is valid until the end of time, as long as the code remains unchanged

I would like to verify this is actually true though.  If I change my computer's clock settings to a later date, past when the certificate expires, I get the following Java Exception in IE, Firefox and Chrome:

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date

Does this mean that the applet will actually fail in a few weeks when the Code Signing Certificate expires, or is this test of changing my computer clock just invalid?  Any references either way?

Comment: I have same problem, but using Thawte recomended timestamp server (https://timestamp.geotrust.com/tsa). I also tried http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 and http://tsa.starfieldtech.com.

Comment: Sorry for double-comments, thinking about the error ... is it posible that the "response is unreliable" message belong to the validation process (OCSP por instance) instead of the certificate validity? I observed that after of deactivating OCSP usage (Java control panel, signing code validation in advanced tab) my applets appears (with computer's clock setttings changed)

Comment: @Gabriel: I'm not really sure who the message belongs to, but I guess its a moot point since I've confirmed tat the certificate still works after it expires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code Signing Certificate has expired several months ago now, and I can confirm everything is still working fine. The Java popup that comes up (the first time visiting the site) says: "The web site's certificate has been verified."

Changing the local timestamp wasn't a valid test of this after all.

Comment: I already confirm that changing local date/time is a valid test when you don't exceed the OCSP response expiration date as we can read in [https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2560.txt] (section 4.2.2.1). In this case Java will inform you through his log that the certificate has expired but exists a timestamp.

Comment: @Gabriel that link is dead https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2560#section-4.2.2.1 still works. But how can we easily check the OCSP response expiration date form a JAR certificate?

Comment: @Gabriel: How do we then test if the code signing is working if we cant do it that way?

Comment: @Gerrat: actually this is not a valid answer - as it is actually not solving the problem of knowing in advance if the certificate is working in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gabriel pointed out in a comment to the original question the problem you experienced was due to revocation checking.

I experienced this while testing with safari, and worked around it by configuring java to allow certificates to be trusted even if revocation status could not be verified, and not to check for certificate revocation.

See the following screen shots from the java console.

[image: Trust even if revocation status could not be verified]
[image: Disable revocation checking]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a proper date on your device
It should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).